# Can I set expectations on mole types created with Moles?

Tags: c#, .net, moles, pex-and-moles

I need to not only swap implementation but also to add necessary check to make sure that certain methods were called in the right order. I can imagine something like Mole + Mock would give me this option. Does anybody know if Moles has this feature?

This code should be helpful:

```
// Verify if Dispose was called
MDisposableObject.Constructor = delegate(DisposableObject instance)
{
    MDisposableObject mole = new MDisposableObject(instance);
    ...
    // This doesn't work 
    //objectContext.Expects(i => i.Dispose()).ToBeCalledOneTime();
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moles aim to give **stubs** (and **not mocks**) for everything, even for static or sealed methods. It's written in the Moles manual that they are not aiming the mocking aspect like others mocking frameworks : they offer isolation, not mocks. If you want to check calls on your Moles, you have to do your own way.
For example:

```
    bool called = false;
    MDisposableObject.Constructor = (@this) =>
    {
        var mole = new MDisposableObject(@this)
        {
            Dispose = () =>
                {
                    Assert.IsFalse(called);
                    called=true;
                    //if you want to call the original implementation:
                    MolesContext.ExecuteWithoutMoles(() => (@this).Dispose());
                    //or do something else, even nothing
                }

        };
    };
```

Only [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/) (powerfull but expensive) and [JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx) of Telerik (new concurrent, also not free) enable mocking features for everything.
If you have some interfaces, delegates and virtual method, use free mocking framework like Moq or RhinoMocks.

A warning about my example: until now I didn't found how to call the orignal constructor, I mean something like

```
var mole = new SDisposable();
(@this) = mole;
new MDisposable(mole) {...};
```

Actually, from what I read on msdn, it's not possible... I hope following releases will enable that.